# Слои в API Яндекс Карты

Tags: яндекс-карты

Всех с Новым годом. Прошу помочь разобраться со слоями карты. Пытаюсь на JS сделать карту РФ с Zoom 8. Проблема в следующем: если использую zoom 7, то на карте не отображается Растительность, что меня устраивает, но я не вижу достаточное кол-во населенных пунктов. Если я делаю zoom 8, то я вижу Растительность (где растет лес), которая отображается зеленым цветом.

Вот у меня есть вопрос -- как сделать так, чтобы при zoom 8 не отображалась Растительность. Другими словами мне нужны только дороги, вода (реки, озера и т.д.), но не нужна Растительность. На Народных картах это сделать можно, просто сняв галочку, а вот как это сделать на стандартных Яндекс Картах я так и не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, так сделать нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Значит буду использовать максимально возможный Zoom=7,499